# DLR Language Design Example

Tags: .net, dynamic-language-runtime

Can someone point me to an example of building a simple hosted language using the DLR? My needs are modest, basically I just want to be able to evaluate simple case-insensitive expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *[DLR - Build Your Own Language (without tears)](http://bitwisemag.com/2/DLR-Build-Your-Own-Language.html)* by Dermot Hogan
- *[Getting started with the DLR: ToyScript](https://web.archive.org/web/20081220204439/http://www.iunknown.com/2007/06/getting_started.html)* by John Lam

Comment: The first link is now broken - Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20160801003906/http://www.bitwisemag.com/2/DLR-Build-Your-Own-Language.html

Answer (score 3):

The CodePlex DLR site includes a walk through of a simple LISP like language called Sympl:

http://dlr.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Docs%20and%20specs&referringTitle=Home

There are implementations in both C# and IronPython.